# Access to google search console api through google app engine (read-only file system)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-search-console

When I use oauth2client.file.storage.get() in an google app engine application, it returns IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename). The log stack is shown below:

```
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\main.py", line 291, in main
run_wsgi_app(app)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 101, in run_wsgi_app
run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\util.py", line 119, in run_bare_wsgi_app
result = application(env, _start_response)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__
response = self._internal_error(e)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\main.py", line 216, in get
response = service.searchanalytics().query(siteUrl=property_uri, body=request).execute()
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\googleapiclient\http.py", line 836, in execute
method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\googleapiclient\http.py", line 167, in _retry_request
resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\oauth2client\transport.py", line 186, in new_request
credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\oauth2client\client.py", line 761, in _refresh
self._do_refresh_request(http)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\oauth2client\client.py", line 802, in _do_refresh_request
self.store.locked_put(self)
File "c:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\gsc2gbq-test\oauth2client\file.py", line 85, in locked_put
f = open(self._filename, 'w')
File "C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\stubs.py", line 278, in __init__
raise IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename) IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: './webmaster_credentials.dat'
```

In order to get access to Google Search Console API, I use the following piece of code to authenticate and access to the google search console API. And I think it is the cause of the problem.

```
# Prepare the API service
    from oauth2client.file import Storage

    storage = Storage("webmaster_credentials.dat")
    credentials = storage.locked_get()

    http_auth = httplib2.Http()
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(http_auth)
    service = build('webmasters', 'v3', http=http_auth, cache_discovery=False)
```

I have done some research on this. Some smart people pointed out that this is because the google app engine is read-only system.

My questions are: **how can I access to google search console API in Google app engine and how can I tackle the issue: IOError(errno.EROFS, 'Read-only file system', filename).**

I appreciate your replies or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own question is solved. So I post my solution here and hope it could help you out there when you read this.

The problem was the short-live token for credential file has to be refreshed and thus new token has to be written to the the credential file on google app engine.

I could not have this done by using:

```
from oauth2client.file import Storage

storage = Storage("webmaster_credentials.dat")
credentials = storage.locked_get()
```

Instead, using the following authentication method solved my problem once for all :P.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials(access_token=access_token, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret,
                                    refresh_token=refresh_token, token_expiry=token_expiry, token_uri=token_uri, user_agent=user_agent, revoke_uri=revoke_uri)
```

You just need to define the variables with your credentials from google app  engine or from other google apis.

Good luck and happy debugging!